# How do I add comments to dockerd daemon.json?

Tags: json, docker, docker-daemon

I checked documentation https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/ and researched the net, but found no answer. How to add comments to deamon.json in docker daemon?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you could not because it is a JSON file, which does not accept any kind of comment syntax.

Neither adding a dummy extra JSON field, name for example `comments`, works, beacause it causes a daemon startup failure (I tried it before writing this answer).

[Here](https://reqbin.com/json/5wzepqmt/json-comment-example#:%7E:text=Can%20I%20add%20a%20comment,elements%20will%20still%20be%20data.) you can find a complete description of this issue. The article tells about the **Microsoft JSONC (JSON with Comments)** format.

A simple and stupid workaround maybe a README file to describe the settings placed into `/etc/docker`.